# Is Xen virtualization similar with amazon's S3 creating an instance?

Tags: virtualization, vps, xen

Hi is Xen virtualization similar with Amazon's S3 creating an instance? What's the difference between then and what about cloud computing? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

As a matter of fact, Amazon S3 is based on Xen. When you set up your Xen server, you get the same hypervisor features but none of the "shiny" features such as on-demand provisionning and hypervisor load balancing.

These tools make the difference between "cloud computing" and "my hypervisor".

Comment: Amazon S3 is a storage service. I think you, and the original poster, are confusing S3 with EC2.

Comment: Oh my bad. You are perfectly right =)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's broadly similar, they both use hypervisor techniques to allow VMs to exist. Clouds are really just a bunch of virtualised hosts that run VMs, usually with little user control/visibility of where the VM actually executes.